# Regular expression to capture & fix a version number

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to create a regular expression to extract version numbers. Since the source who provide those version strings is mostly unreliable I need to clean those values.

A version is a number or a group of numbers separated by only one dot. As soon as the chain is broken I stop capturing and I keep what was captured so far.

Test cases:

```
Foo 1.2.3.4.5 bar --> Should capture 1.2.3.4.5
Foo 111111.2..3.4.5 bar --> Should capture 111111.2
Foo 10.. bar --> Should capture 10
1.2.3 aaa --> Should capture 1.2.3
aaa 1.2.3 --> Should capture 1.2.3
1.23 --> Should capture 1.23
```

I found out some examples but none matches my edge cases (see 3rd case outlined above).

So far I have:

```
/(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)/i
```

But it does not cover all my cases... I use that with PHP (pcre).

Comment: You don't think it would be helpful to identify, at least, the problematic cases?

Comment: Use `preg_match('~\d+(?:\.\d+)*~', $s, $match)`  if you are using PHP and cannot rely on any context.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I did but it was not clear. Should be better now.

Comment: @AlexV yup then the use of the second `+` is your problem, you're forcing the presence of a `.` with it. Replace by `*` and you'll be fine (except that you'll match every single number in your data, which might be a new problem)

Comment: Does [`(?<=\s|^)\d+(?:\.\d+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/8vuuVH/1) work for you?

Comment: @Scott Hunter "Captures" mean "Should capture" sorry changed my wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the following :

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

This matches a number which can be followed by any amount of [ dot and number ].

The difference with your regex is the use of a `*` which enables capturing versions composed of a single number.

I've also removed the outer grouping parenthesis which likely serve no purpose.

Comment: would it make sense to add `[^.]` in the beginning so it does not matches residues ?

Comment: Friend your above post will not work https://regex101.com/r/ZOf0y4/2 make it correct It is also capturing `3.4.5` which is not at all required.

Comment: @SahilGulati I don't see the difference apart from the outer parenthesis, and I don't see what they fix, unless you're expecting the version number in the first group (while you could get it from the whole match)

Comment: @GarisMSuero it shouldn't, this is supposed to match the version from anywhere in the string

Comment: @GarisMSuero actually I don't think I understand what you meant. Note that the leading `\d+` already can't match `.`

Comment: my proposal of improvement of this answer: `(?<![.\d])\d+(?:\.\d+){0,5}` - note some RE implementations are not supporting negative look-behind.

Comment: @MarekR I don't get the lookbehind : the `\d` is clearly superfluous as the first number of a line will be matched by the regex anyway, and I don't get why we shouldn't match `1.2.3` from `.1.2.3` but match it from `foo1.2.3`. We don't know the data of OP, but I wouldn't be surprised by a `product.1.2.3` string for a `product` product in version `1.2.3`. The more strict quantifier could be nice, or maybe not, we don't know. Really I'm just implementing what OP asked for, `A version is a number or a group of numbers separated by only one dot`

Comment: I meant, that your current regex will return two matches with this: `111111.2..3.4.5`

Comment: @GarisMSuero only if you ask it to. OP specifies `As soon as the chain is broken I stop capturing and I keep what was captured so far.`, I expect him not to use the `g`lobal flag nor to use his language's `find_all()` or equivalent. For instance with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jE7MxS/1) if I don't specify the `g`lobal flag only `111111.2` is matched.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZOf0y4/4)

**Regex:** `^[^\d]+\s*\K(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `[^\d]+\s*` match all except digit then `spaces`
>
> **3.** `\K` will reset the match.
>
> **4.** `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` this will match `digits` and then existence of zero or more patterns of `.` and `digits`

**Solution 2:**

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZOf0y4/3)

**Regex:** `^Foo\s*\K(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `Foo\s*` this will match `Foo` and `spaces`
>
> **3.** `\K` will reset the match.
>
> **4.** `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` this will match `digits` and then existence of zero or more patterns of `.` and `digits`

Comment: I don't think OP wants to match `Foo` btw, but rather placed it here as a filler to mean that the version could be anywhere in the string, rather than at the beginning.

Comment: @Aaron I have updated my post you can check the second solution, Is that fine.

Comment: I don't want to match "foo". It was just to illustrate that a version string can be at the beginning, middle or end of a string. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @AlexV I have updated my post , you can check my first solution.

Comment: @SahilGulati now you won't match versions if they are at the start of the string, since your `[^\d]` has to occur at least once ;) Anyway I don't see why you would want an anchored regex here

Comment: @SahilGulati also `\K` isn't defined in every PCRE implementation (although it is implemented in PHP 5.2.4+, so it may not matter to OP)

Comment: @Aaron Is it so, but i dont think so, it is defined, might be you are right.

Comment: @SahilGulati actually I don't know, I was basing my claim over the fact that Java doesn't implement it, but its regex implementation is PCRE-based at best